# Could not update Copay to 5.2.0

Tags: copay

After you release about "Statement on NPM Package Vulnerability in v5.0.2-5.1.0 of Copay Wallets".
I could not update the wallet to 5.2.0. In App Store there is only 5.1.0 version.
Iphone 5se, iOS 12.1
What should I do? And hoe to secure my funds?

Answer (score 2):

To clarify: CoPay has no relation to Bitcoin.SE, it was CoPay that issued that statement regarding the vulnerability. Bitcoin is a decentralized cryptocurrency, and Bitcoin.SE is a technical Q/A help site.

---

The [statement released by CoPay/BitPay](https://blog.bitpay.com/npm-package-vulnerability-copay/) says the following:

> A security update version (5.2.0) has been released and will be available for all Copay and BitPay wallet users in the app stores momentarily.

If you do not see the v5.2.0 app available yet, I would suspect it will be available shortly. In the meantime, according to the statement above, **do not open or run the old version of the app**. Wait until the updated app is published, and then upgrade your app and follow any instructions provided by CoPay/Bitpay.